# Systematic way to determine the ansatz and sign in eigenvalue problem resulting form separation of variables fo Laplace's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

To solve

$$ \nabla^2 u = 0$$

in a rectangle $(0 \leq x \leq L; 0 \leq y \leq H)$ using separation of variables, we assume the solution is of the form

$$u(x,y) = h(x)\phi(y)$$

or

$$u(x,y) = h(y)\phi(x)$$

to obtain two ODEs (one of which is an eigenvalue problem in for $\phi$).

$$\dfrac{1}{h} \dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2} = - \dfrac{1}{\phi} \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dy^2} = \pm \lambda$$

or

$$\dfrac{1}{h} \dfrac{d^2h}{dy^2} = - \dfrac{1}{\phi} \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2} = \pm \lambda$$

Apparently, the imposed boundary conditions determine which 1- ansatz to use from the above, and 2- the sign of the separation constant $\lambda$. Examples for specific choices that I came across are for the follwoing sets of boundary conditions:

a) $u(0,y) = f(y); u(L,y)=u(x,0)= u(x,H) = 0$

$$u(x,y) = h(x) \phi(y)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{h} \dfrac{d^2h}{dy^2} = - \dfrac{1}{\phi} \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2} = -\lambda$$

b) $u(x,H) = f(y); u_x(0,y) = u_x(L,y)=u(x,0) = 0$

$$u(x,y) = h(x) \phi(y)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{h} \dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2} = - \dfrac{1}{\phi} \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dy^2} =  -\lambda$$

c) $u(L,y) = f(y); u_x(0,y) =u(x,0)= u(x,H) = 0$

$$u(x,y) = h(x) \phi(y)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{h} \dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2} = - \dfrac{1}{\phi} \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dy^2} =  \lambda$$

My questions how choose the appropriate ansatz and sign of $\lambda$. What is the reasoning and systematic way behind it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the "different" types of ansatz you showed are **exactly** the same, since you do not know the $h,\phi$ or $\lambda$ at this point. For this reason you do not need to worry about the sign on front of the $\lambda$, that comes later. So your separation of variables ansatz is simply
$$
u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)\Rightarrow X''Y+XY''=0\Rightarrow \frac{X''}{X}=-\frac{Y''}{Y}=\lambda
$$
now the introduction of boundary conditions is straightforward, we just plug in the ansatz. Lets start with homogenous Dirichlet $u(x,0)=u(x,H)=u(0,y)=u(L,y)=0$:
$$
u(x,0)=X(x)Y(0)=0\Rightarrow Y(0)=0\\
u(x,H)=X(x)Y(H)=0\Rightarrow Y(H)=0\\
u(0,y)=X(0)Y(y)=0\Rightarrow X(0)=0\\
u(L,y)=X(L)Y(y)=0\Rightarrow X(L)=0
$$
Here I have omited the trivial solution $X(x)=0$ or $Y(y)=0$ which both yield $u(x,y)=0$.
If we now solve the ODEs
$$
X''=\lambda X, X(0)=X(L)=0
$$
we find that
$$
X(x)=c\sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}x) \text{ for } \lambda=-\frac{\pi^2 n^2}{L^2}, n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
And therefore $\lambda<0$. Unfortunately the other ODE leads the exact opposite result $\lambda=\frac{\pi^2 n^2}{H^2}$ and therefore in this case the only solution is the trivial solution $u(x,y)=0$.

Looking at your other boundary conditions, the problem is that depending on $f$ a simple separation ansatz might not be sufficient to solve the problem: Indeed if we plug the first set into the ansatz:
$$
u(0,y)=X(0)Y(y)=f(y)\Rightarrow Y(y)=f(y)/X(0)\\
u(L,y)=X(L)Y(y)=0\Rightarrow X(L)=0\\
u(x,0)=X(x)Y(0)=X(x)f(0)/X(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=0\\
u(x,H)=X(x)Y(H)=X(x)f(H)/X(0)\Rightarrow f(H)=0\\
\Rightarrow \begin{cases}f''=-\lambda f, f(0)=f(H)=0\\
X''=\lambda X,X(L)=0\end{cases}
$$

so we see there is a strong assumption on $f$ for the ansatz to work.

Comment: Thanks. I am still not understanding though. Are you saying one choice of sing of $\lambda$ would lead to a contradictory solutions for ODEs? So in effect there is no way to determine the sing a priori?

Comment: The sign depends on the differential equation and the boundary conditions. If you are experienced you know it by looking at it, otherwise you need to plug in the boundary conditions and solve the ODEs.

Comment: Okay :) that's why I asked the question. How do you know it by looking at it?

Comment: if you have solved a couple of them by hand you see that you need (co)sine functions to fulfill certain boundary conditions, which means negative sign in the ODE.

Comment: Not to be nitpicking, but your question was about a *systematic approach*. The systematic approach is to plug in the boundary condition and solve the ODEs.

Answer (score 0):

You're solving $\nabla^2 u = 0$ on a rectangular region $R$ of the plane, which will require boundary conditions on the four edges of $R$. Because of the linearity of $\nabla^2$, you can reduce the problem to solving $\nabla^2=0$ with $3$ of the $4$ boundary conditions being $0$, and the $4$th boundary condition specified as some function which is not identically $0$; then you can add these $4$ solutions in order to obtain the desired solution where all $4$ required edge conditions are satisfied. This approach is justified by the linearity of the Laplacian; non-linear equations cannot generally be reduced in this way.